# How can I apply the chain rule to a multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The chain rule says $\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t),y(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$

If I need to apply the chain rule to for example:

$\frac{d}{dt}u(f(t),g(t)) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt}$ Then is this correct?

Further, if I wanted to apply the chain rule to:

$(\frac{d}{dt}u(f(t),g(t),\frac{d}{dt}v(f(t),g(t),\frac{d}{dt}w(f(t),g(t)))$ would the answer be:

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt},\frac{\partial v}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt},\frac{\partial w}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt}\right)\text{?}$$

Is this the final form of my answer?

I'm supposed to find an expression for $\frac{d}{dt}(\phi(\alpha(t))$ in terms of $u,v,w,f$ and $g$ (and/or their derivatives)

$\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $\phi(x_1,x_2) = (u(x_1,x_2),v(x_1,x_2),w(x_1,x_2))$ is a smooth function

$\alpha(t) = (f(t),g(t))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side quirk answer, you can make general use of chain rule by drawing a diagram with original function say $$\mathbf F(f_1(x_1,x_2,...,x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2,...,x_m),...,f_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_p))$$ by considering it as nodes of each function with arrows going into the next function. For each arrow there will be a derivative, every branch represents a term in its particular chain rule. So each arrow in a branch is a derivative, and each arrow is multiplied with other arrows in the branch to get a term, all branches are then summed. Or use the jacobian to derive the chain rule.

Comment: I find this method in "Advanced Calculus" by Gerald B Folland.

Comment: So does that mean that for my particular question, the answer would be the sum of all the components in $\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt},\frac{\partial v}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt},\frac{\partial w}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dt}\right)\text{?}$? I'm not sure what it means to find an expression in terms of u,v,w,f,g(and/or their derivatives) and i'm not sure if I'm on the right track